# retrieve xml tags from sql table with php

Tags: php, sql

i am trying to retrieve xml tags from a table .
I can't print the tags, just only the values.

for example:

```
<product>
<item>a</item>
<price>20</price>
</product>
```

When i try to print it with php code:

```
$q2 = mysql_query("SELECT * from products");
while ($rowq2 = mysql_fetch_array($q2)) {
echo $rowq2["product_xml"];
}
```

The print is without tags, but i want to print this as it is (with the tags).

Please help me!

Comment: Have you checked the view/page source? Your browser may be interpreting them which is why they're not visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the browser thinks `<product>` is an HTML tag and does not display it.
You need to use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) like this:

```
$q2 = mysql_query("SELECT * from products");
while ($rowq2 = mysql_fetch_array($q2)) {
    echo htmlentities($rowq2["product_xml"]);
}
```